# Git submodules fail to recurse at cloning from private git server

Tags: git, server, private, git-submodules

This question has been asked zillions of times, but always in combination with the use of public git servers such as github. I am in the process of setting up my own private git server, which seems to be going alright, up to the point where I try to clone a project with submodules which I previously committed and pushed myself.

When this question is asked with respect to github, the answer always seems to be that a keypair needs to be generated and the public key needs to be registered with github. I would be happy to register my public key with my private git server, but I cannot find any documentation about this. Is it even possible? Even the documentation from git-scm.com funnel into a github reference.

My private git server is nothing more than a Raspberry Pi with an external harddrive, running Raspbian lite. I have made three projects of which one is a main project which has the other two added as submodule. I can create this as such, commit and push, but when I try to clone it with --recurse-submodules (or without and then submodule init/update), the submodules fail. I can, however, clone the submodules outside the scope of the main project.

I have been fooling around with the network setup, and the Pi has changed IP number a couple of times. When I ran into problems because of that, I setup a DNS entry that points to my router, and added a port forwarding rule to the Pi in the router so I can effectively reach my private server from all over the world. Because the URLs changed, and did not want to end up with remnants of the old URL somewhere, I simply started all three projects again, but that did not help me.

What is going on here? Following log has been anonymized. :)

Update 1: the problem is in the authentication when the submodules are cloned. /var/log/auth.log shows failed logins when a submodule is being cloned as part of the cloning of the main project:

```
Jan 13 15:07:56 raspberrypi sshd[3148]: Failed password for git from 192.168.1.18 port 62855 ssh2
```

Scenario I did that shows the error, and also that a clone of a submodule out of the context of the main project simply succeeds:

```
 E:\Projects>git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/Project1.git
Cloning into 'Project1'...
git@git.domain.com's password:
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

E:\Projects>cp -r Project1.cleanBU/* Project1

E:\Projects>cp -r Project1.cleanBU/.gitignore Project1

E:\Projects>git add Src .gitignore
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

E:\Projects>cd Project1

E:\Projects\Project1>git add Src .gitignore

E:\Projects\Project1>git commit
[master (root-commit) 1e52450] Initial commit
 1145 files changed, 726152 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
...
<<<zapped!>>>
...
 create mode 100644 Src/build.bat

E:\Projects\Project1>git push
git@git.domain.com's password:
Enumerating objects: 550, done.
Counting objects: 100% (550/550), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (527/527), done.
Writing objects: 100% (550/550), 1.27 MiB | 3.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 550 (delta 272), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (272/272), done.
To ssh://git.domain.com/gitdata/Project1.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

E:\Projects\Project1>git submodule add ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project2.git Src/project2
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project2'...
git@git.domain.com's password:
remote: Counting objects: 202, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (162/162), done.
remote: Total 202 (delta 36), reused 202 (delta 36)
Receiving objects: 100% (202/202), 586.16 KiB | 4.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36/36), done.

E:\Projects\Project1>git submodule add ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project3.git Src/project3
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project3'...
git@git.domain.com's password:
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)Receiving objects:  44% (8/18)
Receiving objects: 100% (18/18), 15.94 KiB | 5.31 MiB/s, done.

E:\Projects\Project1>git add .gitmodules

E:\Projects\Project1>git commit
[master d93cfa4] Added project3 and project2 submodules
 3 files changed, 8 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 Src/project2
 create mode 160000 Src/project3

E:\Projects\Project1>git push
git@git.domain.com's password:
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 596 bytes | 596.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git.domain.com/gitdata/Project1.git
   1e52450..d93cfa4  master -> master

E:\Projects\Project1>cd ..

E:\Projects>rm -rf Project1

E:\Projects>git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/Project1.git
Cloning into 'Project1'...
git@git.domain.com's password:
remote: Counting objects: 554, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (259/259), done.
remote: Total 554 (delta 273), reused 549 (delta 272)
Receiving objects: 100% (554/554), 1.27 MiB | 5.96 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (273/273), done.
Submodule 'Src/project2' (ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project2.git) registered for path 'Src/project2'
Submodule 'Src/project3' (ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project3.git) registered for path 'Src/project3'
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project2'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.domain.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project2.git' into submodule path 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project2' failed
Failed to clone 'Src/project2'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project2'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.domain.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project2.git' into submodule path 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project2' failed
Failed to clone 'Src/project2' a second time, aborting
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project3'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.domain.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project3.git' into submodule path 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project3' failed
Failed to clone 'Src/project3'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project3'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.domain.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project3.git' into submodule path 'E:/Projects/Project1/Src/project3' failed
Failed to clone 'Src/project3' a second time, aborting

E:\Anheko\Projecten>git clone ssh://git@git.domain.com/gitdata/project2.git
Cloning into 'project2'...
git@git.domain.com's password:
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Rremote: Total 18 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)eceiving objects:  44% (8/18)
Receiving objects: 100% (18/18), 15.94 KiB | 5.31 MiB/s, done.
```

Comment: I assume that at the `password:` prompts that show, you entered a password. The submodule clones don't pause and ask for a password as they're scripted. Set things up so that you don't need to type in a password, and the clones will finish on their own. There may be a way to configure the submodule clones to pause and ask for a password, but if there is, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Indeed, the password prompt is where I type a password. Your suggestion has two caveats. 1: I don't want everyone to be able to clone my repositories and 2: I am not sure how to set it up that you do not need a password.  Using git daemon perhaps or http(s) this might work? Gonna try git daemon.

Comment: Using git daemon unfortunately failed (cannot push, once it is supposed to transfer objects, nothing happens anymore). It made me look into /var/log on the RasPi, and it turns out that the original problem is indeed an authentication problem of sorts. The syslog explicitely states that there is a failed login for user 'git' when a submodule fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using git daemon perhaps or http(s) this might work? Gonna try git daemon

[`git daemon` has no authentication](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_git_protocol), so won't ask passwords, which means everyone accesing your server would be able to clone the repos.

> I don't want everyone to be able to clone my repositories and 2: I am not sure how to set it up that you do not need a password.

If your server is relying on SSH, you need to your public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) published to `git@yourserver:~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`: any clone would not need for you to enter any password (assuming your private key is not passphrase protected)

```
ssh-copy-id git@yourserver
```

If your server is using an https server, then you would need to cache your credentials (username/password) through a [Git credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) (on a Windows client, for instance, that would be [using the Microsoft GCM](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)).

Comment: This was quite confusing but I think I have now seen the light. The mentioning of the file 'autherized_keys' made me type the right google queries to get there. It started to dawn that I could do the commands I previously tried on the RasPi and left me with a key pair I did not know what to do with, also on my windows laptop using Git Bash. Once the keys were generated there, I could share them with my git server using ssh-copy-id and then I could clone recursively. Joy! Thanks!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Right! I have fixed this... err, typo.